# matlab loop or built in function for row and column coordinates

Tags: matlab, row, coordinates

I need to find the row and column coordinates for my matrix {a} <259x1> from another matrix {data} <259x31878>. I tried using for loops but not sure how to implement the for loop using the matrix list {a}. 
Please help anyone.
Thank you.

UPDATE:
Sorry for the confusion.
Yes, matrix {a} is a subset of matrix {data}. Alternatively, matrix {data} is a superset of matrix {a}. I need to find the row and column locations of the values of matrix {a} in matrix {data}. As you can observe, matrix {data} is so large it is not practical to search each data point individually. 
Thanks again.

Comment: Could you explain what it is you're trying to find?  Is `A` a subset of `data` or are you trying to match values in `A` to values in `data`?  If you are matching values from `A` in `data` do you need to account for multiple matches?

Comment: +1 Ben. A's comment - please clarify your question.

Comment: It sound like you could be talking about a scenario where template matching might be what you want? In which case you could try and find the maximum of `convn(data, a, 'shape', 'same')`

Comment: Oh maybe I misunderstood still - if you're trying to just find all the members of `a` that occur in `data` then amas is right - use `ismember`. You can find neighbouring values by looking at where the `diff` in the ismember result is nonzero.

Comment: However, but ismember just provides 0 or 1 data. I need [r c]=find(data=a). I need more detailed information: for example matrix a (1,1) [r c] = 1, 20939. That's more useful for what I'm researching than just ismember 1.

Comment: Do you want to search for the column that is matrix {a} *as a column* in matrix {data}? Or do you simply want to search for individual values of {a} in {data} regardless of which column they each occur in?

Comment: I need to to search for individual values of {a} in {data} regardless of which column they occur in. {a} values may occur more than once in {data}, but it is ok. If they do occur more than once, I will visually inspect each result.

Comment: @Ansari, both {a} and {data} values are already codified so that they are located on the same rows. So, I really just need column information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a(:,ones(1,size(data,2)))==data
```

This yields logical indices which you can use or you can transform them using find:

```
[r c]=find(a(:,ones(1,size(data,2)))==data)
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! YOU READ MY MIND!!! IT WORKS!!! YOU SAVED ME SO MUCH TIME!!!

Comment: @BernardUntalanJr. the key you're looking for is called Caps Lock and is on the left side of the keyboard ;). Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Check matlab [ismemeber](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html) function.

Comment: I've tried ismember, but it's not what I'm looking for. I need to visually look at the values before and after the target values (i.e., matrix {a}) in matrix {data}.

Answer (score 1):

What about the second output of ismember? It gives you the locations rather than a logical index matrix. Have a look at this question:
[Find index of all (non-unique) elements in a cell array as they appear in a second (sorted and unique) cell array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562196/find-index-of-all-non-unique-elements-in-a-cell-array-as-they-appear-in-a-seco)