# How to find indices of one cell array in another in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two cell arrays, say:

```
a = {'ci' 'fox' 'a' 'd' 'fox' 'b' 'a'}
b = {'a' 'b' 'ci' 'd' 'e' 'fox'}
```

and I need to find the indices in `b` of the elements in `a`.
i.e. I want to get this result:

```
result = [3 6 1 4 6 2 1]
```

I've tried to use `INTERSECT` but with no success
note that repetition is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: If they are stings as in your example then you can use `ismember`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562196/find-index-of-all-non-unique-elements-in-a-cell-array-as-they-appear-in-a-seco

Comment: Always single alphabets as elements?

Comment: it's not always single character, i'll edit to make it clear

Comment: So long as it is always strings `ismember` will work. In fact I'm fairly confident this is an exact duplicate of the question I posted?

Comment: yes, seems exactly the same, Thanks. (im closnig this one...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011724/dan) says, this is duplicate of:
[Find index of all (non-unique) elements in a cell array as they appear in a second (sorted and unique) cell array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562196/find-index-of-all-non-unique-elements-in-a-cell-array-as-they-appear-in-a-seco)

The (good) answer there is:

```
[~,loc]=ismember(a,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your `result = [3 6 1 4 -1 2]` did You made a mistake to include occurence of 'a' and no 'b'? 
Assuming that You are taking only the first occurrence of the b member in a:

```
a = {'ci' 'fox' 'a' 'd' 'b' 'a'}
b = {'a' 'b' 'ci' 'd' 'e' 'fox'}

result  = ones(1,length(a))*-1;
for ii=1:length(b)
   tmp = find(strcmp(a,b(ii)));
   if (tmp > 0)
       result(ii) = tmp(1);
   end
end

result
```

Comment: `ismember` is much cleaner: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562196/find-index-of-all-non-unique-elements-in-a-cell-array-as-they-appear-in-a-seco

Comment: Yes, indeed You are right